# Finding same element in at different indexes in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, search

What I'm trying to do: I am trying to make a program that searches an array for a specific int, and the int may be at many indexes in the array, and I need to print all the indexes (for example 5 shows up twice in the array, so I want to output both the indexes). This must be done using a **linear search** algorithm.

What I've done: I have managed to write a program that outputs the index of the specified int in an array, but it is only able to output the index of first time that the int is in the array. Here is the source code that I've come up with:

```
// This program performs a linear search on a character array

// Author: Y K

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int searchList(int[], int, int); // function prototype 

const int SIZE = 8;

int main()
{
    int nums[SIZE] = {3, 6, -19, 5, 5, 0, -2, 99};
    int found;
    int ch;

    cout << "Enter a number to search for:" << endl;
    cin >> ch;

    found = searchList(nums, SIZE, ch);

    if (found == -1)
        cout << "The number " << ch
             << " was not found in the list" << endl;
    else
        cout << "The number " << ch << " is in the " << found + 1
             << " position of the list" << endl;

    return 0;
}

//*******************************************************************
//  searchList
//
//  task:          This searches an array for a particular value
//  data in:       List of values in an array, the number of
//                 elements in the array, and the value searched for
//                 in the array
//  data returned: Position in the array of the value or -1 if value
//                 not found
//
//*******************************************************************

int searchList(int List[], int numElems, int value)
{
    for (int count = 0; count <= numElems; count++)
    {
        if (List[count] == value)
            return count;
    }

    return -1;  // if the value is not found, -1 is returned
}
```

Comment: `count <= numElems` will access the array out of bounds on the last iteration. Use `<` instead.

Comment: Change `searchList` to return a vector then add to the vector when you find a matching number?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by iteratively calling `searchList` and passing it the remainder of the array each time it returns a valid index.

I moved the code that does the searching to another function to make it easier to call more than once. If all you need to do is search once you can move it back inside `main`.

```
#include <iostream>

int searchList(int[], int, int);

const int SIZE = 8;

void test(int *nums, int numElems, int value)
{
    bool found = false;
    int lastPos = 0;
    int index;
    while ((index = searchList(nums + lastPos, numElems - lastPos, value)) != -1)
    {
        std::cout << "found " << value << " @ " << lastPos + index + 1 << "\n";
        lastPos += index + 1;
        found = true;
    }

    if (!found)
    {
        std::cout << value << " not found.\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    int nums[SIZE] = {3, 6, -19, 5, 5, 0, -2, 99};
    for (int value : {3, 6, -19, 5, 0, -2, 99})
    {
        test(nums, SIZE, value);
    }
    test(nums, SIZE, 1);

    return 0;
}

int searchList(int List[], int numElems, int value)
{
    for (int count = 0; count < numElems; count++)
    {
        if (List[count] == value)
            return count;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

[Demo@CompilerExplorer](https://godbolt.org/z/86Wadb6MW)

Output:

```
found 3 @ 1
found 6 @ 2
found -19 @ 3
found 5 @ 4
found 5 @ 5
found 0 @ 6
found -2 @ 7
found 99 @ 8
1 not found.
```